# Implementing sleep() using SIGALRM

Tags: c, signals

I have tried to replace sleep() by SIGALRM.

```
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

void sig_alrm( int signo )
{
    return; /* return to wake up pause */
}

unsigned int sleep1( unsigned int nsecs )
{
    if( signal( SIGALRM, sig_alrm ) == SIG_ERR )
        return (nsecs);
    alarm( nsecs ); /* starts timer */
    pause(); /* next caught signal wakes */
    return( alarm( 0 ) ); /* turn off timer, return unslept*/
}
```

Is this correct implementation?
Is there another implementation?

Comment: `signal` is deprecated. Use `sigaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real implementation has to handle more conditions:

1. Handle `EINTR`.
2. Handle thread cancellation.

See [glibc implementatiop of sleep()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c;h=46b731e0a7a4c05d571010f7c3179ada591cae05;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 0):

The SIGALARM implementation is seriously legacy, and won't conform modern standards (not least, because if you call it from a library you'll mess with any alarms the application may be using). So it needs another syscall.

Possible choices:

- Use `nanosleep`. It's a syscall on most kernels - it's just a high resolution version of `sleep`, so does the job for you. Note that `sleep` has some junky behaviour if SIGCHLD is ignored, so the glibc implementation blocks and unblocks the signals in its `nanosleep`-wrapping implementation of `sleep` to try and get the legacy behaviour!
- Use `select`. It's a perfectly good choice - use empty FD_SETs and pass in your timeout. Very portable and there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation just mimics the `sleep()` function. But the actual internal implementation is OS-dependent. One simple implementation can be as follows:

The OS puts the process in the `wait queue` along with the time stamp after which it must be executed again. Whenever the time comes, it brings back to the `ready queue` and starts executing the process. You can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719071/how-is-sleep-implemented-at-os-level) for more information.

Comment: That's what his implementation does - using SIGALRM isn't the most "modern" implementation, but it does work, and that's how `sleep()` used to be implemented. He's not asking how the kernel might implement a syscall like `pause()` or `nanosleep()`!

Comment: Well I thought he meant "is this the kernal implementation?". Anyways never mind.