# Php sleep function for delay?

Tags: php, performance, delay, sleep

Suppose a website with 'high' traffic, I want to use the php sleep(4) function to avoid flooding. Is it a good idea or should I use different delay ways ? sleep() keeps a connection open, could this be a problem ?

I do:

```
index.php -> stuff.php -> index.php
```

Stuff.php does something and then sleep(4); so the user waits 4 seconds with a blank screen, and then goes back to index. Thanks.

**Update:** My enemies are both, hackers, that wants a DOS, and stressed pepole that click fast on the search button, lets say... Thats why I would use a server-side delay.

Comment: why not update to a server that can handle 'high' traffic? slowing down everything doesn't seem to be a good idea...

Comment: Imagine some shop queue. Is it good idea to ask people in that queue to wait several minutes before they join to this queue? Good idea is to add additional checkout or reduce time for each client serving some ways. If you want avoid flooding - you should recognize it and limit(some module, that limits rps by ip, for example)

Comment: (Thanks Will and Amaksr... for your opposite answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not good approach because even doing 'sleep' apache/php still occupies OS process for that connection. So, on website with high traffic you will get lots of simultaneously running Apache processes that will eat all your server's RAM.

Instead, You can modify one of your pages and put some Javascript code to it, so it could wait for few seconds, and then navigate to the next page by javascript. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really avoid keeping the connection open, otherwise there's no waiting that could happen. You'd have to either do it client side or server side. However, if you run PHP via [nginx](https://nginx.org) and [`php-fpm`](http://php-fpm.org/), you should be able to get much better performance out of it than, say, Apache 2 and `mod_php` with the Worker MPM.

However, `sleep()` itself is fairly efficient, so you shouldn't have to worry about it eating CPU or anything. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719071/how-is-sleep-implemented-at-os-level) for more information on how it's implemented in the lower layers.

In general, the best way to "wait efficiently" is to be using as much of an asynchronous stack as possible.