# PHP Script execution stops after 60 secs

Tags: php, mysql, passthru

this PHP script gets terminated after 60 seconds.

I have already set:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
```

And want to execute php using `passthru` or exec, and have recursive function to check status in db:

```
function checkstatus() {
    $check_status = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from table where status='1'",$con));

    $status=$check_status["status"];

    if ($status !== "1") {
            passthru("/usr/bin/php  abc.php");
            die();

        } else {
            sleep(30);  
            checkstatus();  
        }
}
```

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: i used recursive function to check status in db and script terminates after 60 secs

Comment: @sagarparad where is your code for this function?

Comment: Try set_time_limit(0); at the top of you script.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## STOP USING `MYSQL_` FUNCTIONS. THEY ARE DEPRECATED AND HAVE BEEN REMOVED FROM MODERN PHP VERSIONS!!

- [Why should I stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
- [How do I update my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390607/how-to-change-mysql-to-mysqli)

---

**`Status` is a MySQL keyword and so should ideally be encapsulated in backticks.**

---

```
$check_status = mysqli_fetch_array(
                mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM table WHERE `status`='1'")
                );
```

Your are only checking the statuses of `where status='1'` . Therefore `if ($status !== "1") {` will **always** be `false`.

Therefore you  will always be sleeping for 30 seconds every time this script runs. This is an infinite waste of server resources.

---

## Question Answer:

To stop the time limit being hit, add [this code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to the top of your script:

```
set_time_limit(0); // set no limit.
```

## However,

Looking at the shape of your script it looks terrible; you [do not want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648609/php-sleep-function-for-delay) to keep PHP hanging on `sleep` statements. Intead you should look into using a [PHP Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) that executes once every 30 seconds.